# Error when trying to Scaffold a model

Tags: razor, scaffold

I'm building a Razor Page app using ASP.NET 2017.  When I run the command

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Activity -dc CongContext -udl -outDir Page\Activities --referenceScriptLibraries
```

This error appears:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
>   Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I stopped and restarted VS, I've also cleaned and build the solution. [Attached jpg shows the code I typed and the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omszk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of different versions of packages. Check the 'Dependencies' node of your project. The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` must have same 2.0.3 versions.

If not, delete and re-add them from [Tools] menu > [Nuget Package Manager]. Also delete the Migrations folder and repeat instructions as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.0). For more info, you may take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6357#issuecomment-388380899)

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track the problem is resolved.  Much appreciated!