# Blazor: creating a razor page returns Error: "There are no scaffolders supported for this item"

Tags: c#, scaffolding, blazor, .net-core-3.0

I'm getting started with Blazor following this [INSTRUCTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)
I'm using  ".NET Core 3.0 Preview SDK" and "Visual Studio 2019 preview".

Following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@st.mas29/microsoft-blazor-web-api-with-jwt-authentication-part-1-f33a44abab9d) I'm encountering an error creating a razor page client side:

> "There are no scaffolders supported for this item"

I found a very [unhappy statement](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/431328/scaffolding-error-there-are-no-scaffolders-support.html) (bottom page at solutions)that makes me think isn't just my problem;

I looked up question similar to mine ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558765/error-when-trying-to-scaffold-a-model), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205382/there-are-no-scaffolders-supported-for-this-item-visual-studio-2019));
the second solution seams pretty straight forward, but the "razor page" created returns a bunch of errors, did I miss something?

my code is [HERE](https://github.com/iapicca/Blazor_Auth_Demo_2)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "There are no scaffolders supported for this item"

Blazor employ Component Model, which does not have any supports for scaffolders, at least not right now. To get rid of these error ? Simply remove everything related to the Default UI, used in Razor Pages and MVC. Again,you should not add the Default UI. Read my previous answer and comments.

I'd suggest you to proceed with my code snippet in my previous answer...

Note: There is no "Razor Page" term or concept in Blazor. "Razor Page" refers to the "Razor Pages" framework, the newly added framework. In Blazor, one may speak of Razor Components or Blazor Components (preferably, to my mind).

Hope this helps...

Comment: you are ubiquitous @issac thanks for the help...
got it, no razor page, but razor componets,
actually copy pasting a random components and changing name and contents seams fine :) thanks again